# raindrop going right except going down

Tags: python, pygame

i'm doing exercise from my python book, and I need make raindrop from top to down, and when it fall behind screen, it's start again. But with my code, my rain going from left to right, and don't reset so it's double failour, under i giving two codes game_functions and raindrop, main code where i open it have only these connections with other code.

```
 gf.update_raindrops(ai_settings, raindrops)
raindrops = Group()
gf.create_grid(ai_settings, screen, ship, raindrops)
```

**game_functions.py**

```
    def get_number_raindrops_x(ai_settings, rain_width):
    
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width
    number_raindrops_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * rain_width))
    return number_raindrops_x

def get_number_rows_rains(ai_settings, ship_height, rain_height):

    available_space_y = ai_settings.screen_height
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / rain_height)
    return number_rows

def create_raindrop(ai_settings, raindrops, screen, raindrop_number, row_number):
    raindrop = Raindrop(ai_settings, screen)
    raindrop.x = raindrop.rect.width + 2 * raindrop.rect.width * raindrop_number
    raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
    raindrop.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
    raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.y
    raindrops.add(raindrop)


def create_grid(ai_settings, screen, ship , raindrops):

    raindrop = Raindrop(ai_settings, screen)
    number_raindrops_x = get_number_raindrops_x(ai_settings, raindrop.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows_rains(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, raindrop.rect.height)

    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for raindrop_number in range(number_raindrops_x):
            create_raindrop(ai_settings, raindrops, screen, raindrop_number, row_number)



def check_grid_edges(ai_settings, raindrops):
    for raindrop in raindrops.sprites():
        if raindrop.check_edges():
            change_grid_direction(ai_settings, raindrops)
            break


def change_grid_direction(ai_settings, raindrops):
    for raindrop in raindrop.sprites():
        raindrop.rect.y == ai_settings.rain_drop_speed
    
            

def update_raindrops(ai_settings, raindrops):
    check_grid_edges(ai_settings, raindrops)
    raindrops.update()
```

**rain.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Raindrop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Raindrop, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        self.image = pygame.image.load('/Users/dominikkolber/Desktop/graphic/drop.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            return True
        
    
    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.rain_drop_speed)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to let the rain fall instead of moving it left to right, you'll have to change the `y` coordinate instead of the `x` coordinate:

```py
class Raindrop(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        # [...]

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.y += (self.ai_settings.rain_drop_speed)
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

If the raindrop hits the bottom, you need to restart it at the top by changing the `y` attribute of the individual raindrop:

```py
def check_grid_edges(ai_settings, raindrops):
    for raindrop in raindrops.sprites():
        if raindrop.check_edges():
            raindrop.y = 0
```

Comment: and how can i make to repeat falling raindrop? because it's fell only once

Comment: @sneakyarthur I've extended the answer.